# MVC 4 iframe embedded in desktop page showing mobile view

Tags: iframe, redirect, routes, asp.net-mvc-4

I use Index.cshtml and Index.mobile.cshtml. My Index.cshtml is a mobile app landing page containing an iframe to live demo the mobile web app. Index.mobile.cshtml is the mobile web app itself.

The problem is, the iframe keeps loading the desktop version itself. As far as I know, I cannot configure the user agent of the iframe to a mobile type. It should be solvable with some routing but I couldn't figure out how!?

**UPDATE**:

I think I found a solution. In the iFrame src I introduce a URL param forceMobile=true :

```
<iframe id="rtnApp" src="/demohcid?forceMobile=true"></iframe>
```

Now in HomeController, I check for this URL Param and if forceMobile, then I return the mobile view, even if the agent is a desktop browser:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Request.Params["forceMobile"] != null) 
            return View("Index.mobile");
        else {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's all standard MVC. Here a sneak preview of what I'm building (German only): http://alpha.rememberthename.ch/Home/DesktopLanding
Now I want to be able to serve this DesktopLanding directly through alpha.rememberthename.ch without having this extra path.